# Must a page be published in order to be added to menu?

Tags: menus

Must a page in WordPress first be published before it can be added to a menu? Or can it be created in draft and then added to a menu?

Answer (score 3):

The page must be published, as detailed in the ["Adding Items to a Menu" section of the WordPress Codex WordPress Menu User Guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide#Adding_Items_to_a_Menu):

> You can add different link types into your menu, these are split between panes left of the menu you're currently editing.
>
> 1. Locate the pane entitled Pages.
> 2. Within this pane, select the View All link to bring up a list of all the **currently published** Pages on your site.
> 3. ...

Follow the link to see the rest of the steps if you need full instructions for adding a page to your menu.